# Simple_form not validating input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a rails app where a user submits a form to create an item and then gets redirected to their item they have just created.

Problem I'm having is that if all the fields are left empty, or even one of the required fields is left empty, then the data still gets passed and a new item is created.

I've used the `required: true` property thinking that this will make sure that data is entered, and then no data is entered an error will occur. Although this isn't working.

In the `config/initializaers/simple_form.rb` file, the `config.browser_validations = true` is set to true.

Anybody know why the input is still passing through?

Simple form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>

  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }, input_html: { class: " dropdown-toggle" } %>

  <%= f.input :name, label: "Your Name", required: true, error: 'Your name is required', input_html: { class: "form-control", maxlength: 30} %>

  <%= f.input :title, label: "Item Title", required: true, error: 'Item title is required', input_html: { class: "form-control", maxlength: 50 } %>

  <%= f.input :used?, as: :check_boxes, required: true, label: "Is Your Item Used?" %>

  <%= f.input :price, label: "Item Price", required: true, error: 'Price is required', input_html: { class: "form-control", :placeholder => "$" }  %>

  <%= f.input :description, label: "Item Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.input :email, label: "Email", required: true, error: 'Email is required', input_html: { class: "form-control", :placeholder => "user@email.com" } %>

  <%= f.input :phone, label: "Phone Number", input_html: { class: "form-control", :placeholder => "+61 --- --- ---", :value => "+61 " } %>

  <%= f.input :suburb, label: "Suburb", required: true, error: 'Suburb is required', input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>

  <%= f.input :image, label: "Upload An Image (Must be less than 2mb)" %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Item Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
end
```

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def show
end

def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
end

def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(items_params)

        if @item.save
            redirect_to @item
        else
            render "New"
        end
end

def edit
end

private

def items_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :title, :price, :description, :used?, :email, :phone, :suburb, :category_id, :image, :search)
end

def find_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the simple_form documentation:

> By default all inputs are required. When the form object has presence
>   validations attached to its fields, Simple Form tells required and
>   optional fields apart. For performance reasons, this detection is
>   skipped on validations that make use of conditional options, such as
>   :if and :unless.

You can add validations for presence in your Item model, e.g. `validates :name, presence: true` You will not need to include the messages manually this way for each input.

Comment: Great thanks, I just deleted the required property from the form, and added the validation to the model and it works! Is there any way that when the user click on the submit button, but hasn't filled out all of the required fields, an error pops up saying something along the lines of "you need to fill in all required fields"?

Comment: Glad it worked. The rails validations documentation probably has the answers you're looking for--check out the section on `:message` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message)

Comment: Thanks. Also, I just got a problem, when I submit the form with all the inputs filled in, I get this error `Missing template items/New, application/New with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

Its telling me a template is missing, although in the past when I had filled out forms it just redirected me to the item I had just created

Comment: Using `new` instead of `build` your new action may be something to explore (with the pertinent changes and association with User in place).

Comment: No worries, I just figured out why. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a simple browser validation that prevents the user from submitting if the required field is not filled in. By default simple_form turns off browser validation.

You can turn it on in the configuration file, if you do not have the configuration file, you can generate it with the following command:

```
rails generate simple_form:install
```

config > initializers > simple_form

```
# Tell browsers whether to use the native HTML5 validations (novalidate form option).
# These validations are enabled in SimpleForm's internal config but disabled by default
# in this configuration, which is recommended due to some quirks from different browsers.
# To stop SimpleForm from generating the novalidate option, enabling the HTML5 validations,
# change this configuration to true.

  config.browser_validations = true
```